# OperationFailure: unknown top level operator: $ne (Monogbd)

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

What is wrong with this code? When I try to run it I get OperationFailure: unknown top level operator: $ne full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'unknown top level operator: $ne', 'code': 2, 'codeName': 'BadValue'}.

Any ideas what this means? Thank you in advance :)

```
import pandas as pd

def length_vs_references(articles):

    res = {"1-5" : 0, "6-10" : 0, "11-15" : 0, "16-20" : 0, "21-25" : 0, "25-30" : 0, ">30" :0}
    n = {"1-5" : 0, "6-10" : 0, "11-15" : 0, "16-20" : 0, "21-25" : 0, "25-30" : 0, ">30" :0}
    
    cursor = articles.aggregate([
        {'$match': {'$and' : [{'references': {'$exists': False}
        }, {'$ne':['$page_end', '']}, {'$ne':['$page_start', '']} ]}},
        {'$project': {'len_refernces': {"$size": '$references'},
                                                'pages': {'$subtract': [{"$toInt": 'page_end'},
                                                                        {"$toInt" : 'page_start'}]}}},
        
            {'$bucket' :{
            '$groupBy': '$pages',
            'boundaries': [ 0, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 1000000],
                'default': 'Other',
             'key': {
                 'output': {"average": {"$avg" : '$len_references'}},
            }
                }
            }       
    ])
    return cursor
     
    
print(length_vs_references(articles))
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading between the lines I suspect you want:

```
cursor = articles.aggregate([
    {'$match': {'references': {'$exists': False}, 'page_end': {'$ne': ''}, 'page_start': {'$ne': ''}}},
    {'$project': {'len_refernces': {"$size": '$references'},
                  'pages': {'$subtract': [{"$toInt": '$page_end'},
                                          {"$toInt": '$page_start'}]}}},

    {'$bucket': {
        'groupBy': '$pages',
        'boundaries': [0, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 1000000],
        'default': 'Other'
    }
    }
])
```

You don't need to `AND` your match filters as they are `AND`ed by default. I'm guessing you are trying to filter out blank `page_end` and `page_start` items. If not, please describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do. When I removed the AND filters I get syntax error on File "<ipython-input-17-728073f2f109>", line 17
    {"$toInt" : 'page_start'}]}}},
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: OK you had a few other issues with the code; I;'ve updated my answer. I've removed `key` fromt he bucket command as it isn't part of the syntax - you'll need to check that.

Comment: Once I remove key I get another OperationFailure! OperationFailure: The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing', 'code': 17124, 'codeName': 'Location17124'}

Comment: For contact I am trying to answer the question Do longer articles (in number of pages) have more references? using a histogram and returning a dictionary